# Multi flow storage tank issue

Tags: excel-formula

I have a set of data where varying volumes of gas are being produced every hour of the year (8760 data points) (say i1,i2,...i8760), this gas gets stored in a tank of volume "V". This gas will run one or two engines based on the following criteria:
Run engine 1 all the time which consumes volume A every hour
Run engine 2 when the volume stored in the tank exceeds 0.75*V and run until it falls to 0.25*V

How can I create a model for this in excel? I want to calculate the no. of hours engine 1 and engine 2 can run in a year with the above mentioned constraints.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Thinking this is like one-compartment model in pharmacokinetics, but a quick search of the PK literature doesn't seem to help much. On the face of it doesn't sound too difficult, but granularity of model would depend on volumes of gas in/out vs. size of tank. Will try and sketch an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The various constants are set up in cells A2:E2 then there are 3 formulae:-

In J3, it just adds the new input volume to the volume at the end of the previous cycle:-

```
=L2+I3
```

In K3, it tests to see if engine B should run:-

```
=OR(J3>$D$2,AND(K2,J3>$E$2))
```

In L3, it works out the volume at the end of the cycle:-

```
=IF(K3,J3-$B$2-$C$2,J3-$B$2)
```

It needs some more work to deal with the cases where the tank gets completely full or completely empty.

[image]